# iOS Phonegap 2.5 - Cross-device link error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode4.6

When generating a blank iOS phonegap project I get 25 errors that say "Cross-device link".

I am guessing anyone generating a blank project will see the same thing...

Here is a screenshot for your viewing pleasure:

[image: Error Screenshot]

I have done quite a bit of searching on this but haven't come up with any solutions or clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was originally creating the project to a network drive which was never an issue with past versions of phonegap but I went ahead and tried creating it locally which stopped all of the Cross-device link errors.

So I guess this is sort of a fix but it still seems like there must be a bug or something with 2.5

> Update:
>
> Shazron Abdullah from the Phonegap mailing list confirmed this and suggested that I submit a bug report.
>
> Mailing list thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/QhrbCwilGKo
>
> Bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2618